# Why aren't my tables showing up in my DbContext?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

Long-story-short, if you look at [my project](https://github.com/jamkin/lrvault/tree/master/LRVault) you can see that I have an [automatically generated model](https://github.com/jamkin/lrvault/blob/master/LRVault/Models/vault.Context.cs), but after importing the namespace of the mode and trying to use it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using LRVault.Models;
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace LRVault.Repositories
{
    public class ThreadRepository : VaultCRUD
    {
        public void AddOrUpdateThreads(IEnumerable<Thread> threads)
        {
            VaultContext.???
        }
    }
}
```

I can't get the tables, i.e. `VaultContext.Posts` is unrecognized. What am I missing?

EDIT: parent class is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Linq;
using LRVault.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace LRVault.Repositories
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serves as base class for the CRUD operations
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class VaultCRUD : IDisposable
    {
        public DbContext VaultContext { get; private set; } 

        public VaultCRUD()
        {
            VaultContext = new LRC_VAULTEntities(); 
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            VaultContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have a `new` in your `using` statement?  Does that compile?

Comment: The parent class's constructor has `VaultContext = new LRC_VAULTEntities(); `

Comment: What's the scope of `VaultContext` in the parent class?  Can you please post the code for the parent class?

Comment: @DavidTansey Sure, I'll post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast VaultContext property to `LRC_VAULTEntities`, to access the tables:

```
(VaultContext as LRC_VAULTEntities).
```

`DbContext` is the base class of `LRC_VAULTEntities`, but the 'Tables' are in `LRC_VAULTEntities`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance,

```
using(var context = new  VaultContext())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `VaultContext` instance is declared with type `DbContext` which has nothing to do with your table, you have to change its type to be `LRC_VAULTEntities`, do this and you will get your tables as you want in the inherited classes